# Can Kernel Modules Have Configuration Files Instead of Using Proc or SysFS

Tags: configuration, linux-device-driver, configuration-files, kernel-module, proc

I'm writing a kernel module that requires a good amount of configuration options with no default values.  Is it acceptable for a kernel module to access a configuration file (I'm guessing stored in /etc)?  Or is that frowned on and I should be using the proc or sys file system in combination with a long list of module parameters passed in when the module is loaded?  Any documentation on this subject or relevant examples?

Comment: In a form of a firmware interface: `request_firmware()`.

Comment: You might be able to do something clever with [configfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/configfs.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want some module to be loaded at boot time, just create the file /etc/modules- load.d/.conf, and add the module's name that should be loaded, one per line.  should be meaningful to you, and people usually use module:/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf. You may create as many .conf files as you need